# How to plot subcategories and their parents in R

Tags: r, visualization, categories, dendrogram, family-tree

I am totally lost for an easy plot. All i want to do is something like a dendrogram, but without any calculations. A simple, treelike structure to show which subcategories belongs to which category and so on.
My columns are looking like this:

```
category, subcategory, sub-subcategory, n
```

filled with strings. There are 4 categories and multiple split downs. There are no duplicates, each sub-subcategory is distinct to one subcategory and one category. Dont really need to be able to plot n aswell.

I guess what i am missing is the real name for such a diagram. Whatever I google, I always just find classification trees or dendrograms, which both is way too much for my needs.

It would be awesome if someone can give me some hints.

Comment: I've used igraph. the tkplot function lets you plot interactively.

Comment: Maybe this?
https://github.com/yonicd/SearchTree